# AngularJS filter array list by clicking on separate tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array list that that displays a user's meeting name and location. By default, I am filtering the list to display meeting name and would like to have an option to click on a tab that would then filter the list by location name. This is currently what I have:

Array List:

```
$scope.requests = [
    {
        type: "meeting1",
        meetingName: "Radiology San Diego",
        location:"Sheraton Ballroom 5S",
        subitems: [
            {
                name: "ESCALATED",
                desc: "Power strips at every table",
                priority:"1"
            },
            {
                name: "OPEN",
                desc: "Extra table for 3",
                priority:"3"
            },
            {
                name: "ACKNOWLEDGED",
                desc: "Projector for meeting",
                priority:"2"
            },
            {
                name: "CLOSED",
                desc: "Sub-Item 2",
                priority:"5"
            },
            {
                name: "CANCELLED",
                desc: "Sub-Item 2",
                priority:"1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "meeting2",
        meetingName: "California Almond Growers",
        location:"Sheraton FL14",
        subitems: [
            {
                name: "ESCALATED",
                desc: "Sub-Item 1",
                priority:"1"
            },
            {
                name: "OPEN",
                desc: "Sub-Item 2",
                priority:"4"
            },
            {
                name: "ACKNOWLEDGED",
                desc: "Sub-Item 2",
                priority:"2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "meeting3",
        meetingName: "Association of Amateur Archaeologists",
        location:"Ansley 1- FL14",
        subitems: [
            {
                name: "ESCALATED",
                desc: "Sub-Item 1",
                priority:"1"
            },
            {
                name: "OPEN",
                desc: "Sub-Item 2",
                priority:"3"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

JSP:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a id="tab-meeting" data-toggle="tab"
           ng-click="tab(1)">By MEETING</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="tab-location" data-toggle="tab" 
           ng-click="tab(2)">By LOCATION</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="requestView">
    <div class="requestInformation" 
         ng-repeat="mName in requests | filter:name | orderBy:sort">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h4 ng-model="filterRequest">{{mName.location}}</h4>
            </div>
```

JS to switch tabs:

```
$scope.orderProp='location';

$scope.tab = function (tabIndex) {
    //Sort by meeting name
    if (tabIndex == 1){
        //alert(tabIndex);
        $scope.orderProp='meetingName';

    }
    //Sort by meeting location
    if (tabIndex == 2){
        $scope.orderProp = 'location';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking for a filter ? The filter you are using selects a subset of items in your main list, based on the criteria you provide. At the moment, unless there is a $scope.name variable somewhere that you didn't show, your filter probably does nothing.

Supposing you are really trying to select only a subset of items (e.g. only meetings at the Sheraton), filtering accepts several valid syntaxes; the one you are using actually searches all fields for the constraint. To specifically filter by a given field, use `filter:{field:constraint};`
if you wish, you can combine several criteria in the same filter object. Also note that you can add :true (as in `filter:object:true`) if you wish to make it a strict search.

Also note that, unless I have missed something, you could do without your sort function and simply use `| orderBy : criterium` ; but I'm not certain your sort is doing what you want it to do : at the moment, if you have indeed selected items based on their meeting name, all share the same name (or something similar, if you didn't do a strict search) and you are basing your ordering on this.

Comment: Sorry I think my description was slightly confusing...currently, I am displaying my array list by meetingName...on click of the "by Location", I am aiming to display my list by it's location name.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still unclear on what you want to do that is neither covered by filter nor by sort ? Do you want to just display the location name of the meeting name ? If so, just do {{mName[orderProp]}} to select the field you want to display ?